mongo aggregation - avoid returning an empty object when unwinding with preserveNullAndEmptyArrays and group with a subField
I'm struggling to get the aggregation pipeline to give me the exact format I'm looking for in Mongo.
I am using unwind but in cases where I have an empty array I need to use the preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true option to not lose the rest of my object.
But then when I regroup at the end of my pipeline instead of an empty array I get an array with a single empty object.
I've come up with a workaround in my api but I'd really rather fix the aggregation pipeline.
Example in Mongo Playground
Here's my example:
db.produce.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$produceItems",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "fruits",
      localField: "produceItems.item",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "fruitProperties"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "vegetables",
      localField: "produceItems.item",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "vegetableProperties"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "produceItems.properties": {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $first: "$fruitProperties"
          },
          {
            $first: "$vegetableProperties"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      produceItems: {
        $push: "$produceItems"
      }
    }
  }
])

And when the produceItems = [] in the database object I'd like to have this response:
Desired response:
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "produceItems": []
  }
]

Actual response:
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "produceItems": [
      {}   // <-- I don't want to get this empty object element in my array
    ]
  }
]

The pipeline works well if I have anything in the produceItems array but not if it's null.
My issue seems to be that in my $addFields call I'm using a subField.  So the parent field gets created automatically.
Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way and there's a simpler way to do what I'm trying to do?

A quick and dirty fix could be simply adding a $filter at end of pipeline: https://mongoplayground.net/p/kfkZ18bus3P. In my opinion, a more elegant way would be investigating the cardinality of the produceItems field to see if it is possible to avoid empty lookup

You are explicitly adding that empty object in the $addFields stage.
If we end that pipeline after the lookup (Playground), the result is:
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "fruitProperties": [],
    "vegetableProperties": []
  }

Ending immediately after the $addFields (Playground), the result is:
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "fruitProperties": [],
    "produceItems": {},  //<-- this was added by the $addFields
    "vegetableProperties": []
  }

Using the field name "produceItems.properties" in that manner is telling the stage to create an object in the field "produceItems" and conditionally add fields to the new object.  What you really want is to conditionally create the object.
You might use a second $addFields to check for an empty object, and use "$$REMOVE" to eliminate the empty document:
  {
    $addFields: {
      produceItems: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $eq: [ "$produceItems", {} ]},
          then: "$$REMOVE",
          else: "$produceItems"
        }
      }
    }
  }

Playground
You could also put the $cond directly in the $push, if you think that looks better.

Thank you a ton for this.  The conditional check works perfect!
